# "Has someone smoked" vs. "Has someone been smoking"

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense, perfect-constructions

If I come into a room full of smoke, should I ask:

> **A**: "Has someone smoked here?"

or:

> **B**: "Has someone been smoking here?"

I can literally see the smoke, but the person who was smoking has already gone.

Answer (score 1):

I would either use Question B:

> *Has someone been smoking here?*

or I would ask this version:

> *Did someone just smoke here?*

Question A is problematic because the answer to that question would be "yes" even if the smoking happened five years ago, and it sounds like you are wanting to ask about the very recent past (i.e., a few moments ago).